# How to implement image upload while creating a user directory if he doesn't have one in django?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, django-models

I have two model in my profile that request image upload.

One is just a market place where all the images can be together, i don't care, but the other is a photo gallery. I ready many ways to upload images (most are very old - 2007/2008). and didn't really find the right way yet.

So,Here i am, hoping that i will get my answer here... Is there a a good tutorial that any one know about on how to upload a complex form (two three models inline in one form with image upload for every user to the user directory) ?

I know this might be two questions, but it is connected to the same issue...

10x,

Erez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can write your own [Storage class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-file-storage/) which takes into account the current user to determine the directory to store the file?

Maybe it is even possible to abuse the existing system and change the `FileField.storage` in for example the constructor. I am not sure if this is easily possible, and it will probably be a very dirty solution.

Comment: @Erez, i advise you to implement your own storage backend, like muksie stated - it's more native way.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done with `os.mkdir`

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer over here eventually:

[Upload files by user](http://www.beardygeek.com/2008/11/creating-user-profiles-with-image-thumbnails-in-django/)

If I user this as the base concept, I can actually create what i am looking for....

10x everyone.